# conectar 2 bases de datos con Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, as400

Tengo un proyecto donde trabajar con 2 bases de datos, una es para consultar la cual esta en IBM DB2 i Series AS400 y la otra esta en postgreSql aca les comparto la configuracion de las bases de datos en el archibo database.php:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'postgres',
    'password' => '123456',
    'database' => 'gdrc',
    'dbdriver' => 'postgre',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);



$db['as400'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'gdrc',
    'hostname' => '172.00.00.00',
    'username' => 'Usuario',
    'password' => 'Password123',
    'database' => 'bavcyfiles',
    'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE,
    'autoinit' => FALSE
);
```

en el controlador cargo el modelo y la segunda base de datos de esta manera

```
public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->validarSesion();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('Reclamos_model');
        $this->load->database('as400',true);
    }
```

y tengo una funcion en el modelo para consultar a esta segunda base de datos para obtener los datos del usuario segun su ID, esta es la funcion

```
function buscarPersona($parametros){      
      extract($parametros);

      $this->db_2->select('CUSNA1');
      $this->db_2->from($tabla)
      $this->db_2->where($condicion);

      $rs = $this->db_2->get();
    
      $result = $rs->row_array();

      return $result;
   }
```

adicionalmente en el modelo cargo esta configuracion

```
function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->database();
      $db_2 = $this->load->database('as400', TRUE);
   }
```

pero al consultar me da el siguiente error

> Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::select()

no se si se necesita una configuracion adicional para que codeigniter trabaje con los drivers de odbc adicional a los que ya estan configurados en el php.ini y las extensiones colocadas en la careta ext/ de php

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->load->model("Base_datos_1", "b1");
$this->b1->init("default"); 

$this->load->model("Base_datos_2", "b2");
$this->b2->init("as400");
```

En el modelo tienes que poner esta funcion:

```
public function init($database)
{
    $this->db = $this->load->database($database, TRUE);
}
```